# How do you determine if a stress-energy tensor describes a fluid?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I understand that if a stress-energy tensor can be written in a frame as $T_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(\rho,p,p,p)$ then it describes a perfect fluid, but if you are given a stress-energy tensor in an arbitrary coordinate system, how do you determine if the tensor describes a perfect fluid?

Comment: Possibly related: [Stress energy tensor of perfect fluid in general frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420885/stress-energy-tensor-of-perfect-fluid-in-general-frame)

Comment: $\partial T_{\mu}^{\nu}/\partial x^{\nu}=0\;\; $ ,see :https://archive.org/details/landau-and-lifshitz-physics-textbooks-series/Vol%206%20-%20Landau%2C%20Lifshitz%20-%20Fluid%20mechanics%20%282nd%20ed%2C%201987%29/page/506/mode/1up?view=theater                " ....The energy-momentum tensor (133.2) does not take account of any dissipative processes (including viscosity and thermal conduction), and therefore the equations relate to an ideal fluid"

Comment: See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411934/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27518/226902

Answer (score 7):

> … if you are given a stress-energy tensor in an arbitrary coordinate system, how do you determine if the tensor describes a perfect fluid?

One way to achieve this is to consider [eigenvalue/eigenvector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) at a given point:
$$(T^a{}_b-\lambda \delta^a{}_{b})V^b=0.$$

If there is a timelike eigenvector with one eigenvalue ($\lambda_1=-\rho$, in “mostly plus” signature) and three linearly independent spacelike eigenvectors with another common eigenvalue ($\lambda_2=p_1=p_2=p_3=p$) then such stress-energy tensor can belong to a perfect fluid and the timelike eigenvector ($u^a$, after normalization) would be the 4-velocity of its rest frame. The orthonormal set of eigenvectors at a given point will form a basis for coordinate system where the stress-energy tensor would assume canonical diagonal form. The problem of finding eigenvectors/eigenvalues is usually covered in linear algebra courses and there are many tools for it (algorithms, numerical methods, software etc.).

Another approach to the same problem is to evaluate certain *Rainich-type* conditions, a set of tensor equations written in terms of stress-energy tensor and the metric. And  since stress-energy tensor is expressible via Einstein equations through the curvature tensor, such conditions could be seen as a purely geometric criterion for a metric (taken not just at a point but  in some region)   to constitute  a *perfect fluid spacetime*.

(The original Rainich conditions provided geometric criteria for the metric to define an electrovacuum spacetime).

The paper

- Krongos, D. S., and C. G. Torre. *Geometrization conditions for perfect fluids, scalar fields, and electromagnetic fields.* Journal of Mathematical Physics 56.7 (2015): 072503, [doi:10.1063/1.4926952](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4926952), [arXiv:1503.06311](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06311).

provides the following criteria for a spacetime to have a perfect fluid stress-energy tensor (specialized here for $d=4$).

Define trace-free stress-energy tensor (alternatively, one can instead use trace-free Ricci tensor) $$S_{ab}=T_{ab}-\frac14 T^c{}_c\,g_{ab}$$

and a scalar

$$α = − \left[\frac83 S^b_ aS^c_ bS^a_ c\right]^{1/3} . $$

The metric $g$ defines a perfect fluid spacetime if and only if the following conditions are met \begin{eqnarray}α &\ne &0  \\
 K_{a[b}K_{c]d} &= &0, \\
K_{ab}v^av^b &> &0, \qquad \text{for some }v^a,\end{eqnarray}
where $$K_{ab} = \frac1 α S_{ab} −\frac 1 4 g_{ab}.$$

*Those expressions may seem somewhat arcane, but basically those encode in the language of tensor expressions of the criteria for the necessary eigenvalue/eigenvector structure.*

There is a great deal of overlap in the suggested approaches and which would be better depends on specific problem details and personal preferences.